# remotely determine using ssh IF a machine needs to be rebooted

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, command-line-interface

There are plenty of examples of HOW to reboot a linux machine via SSH. However, in my case I want to check IF a linux machine needs to be rebooted via SSH. I have an agent that checks a machine for various metrics and reports that back to a central alarm console. I want to add the ability to check if a machine requires a reboot since some of them have security updates automatically installing.

I don't want to have to enable something on each machine as I prefer to run one script from one location preferably with a single command to check remotely.

**EDIT**: To clarify, I was looking for a file on a machine that would indicate whether a machine requires a reboot. I then wanted to check for the existence of that file (or something else) remotely using SSH where I am already doing other checks on a group of machines on a nightly basis. I didn't necessarily want to trigger a reboot if it was determined a reboot is required.

The answer I was looking for is below that's referencing `/var/run/reboot-required` which lead me to to [this link](https://serverfault.com/questions/92932/how-does-ubuntu-keep-track-of-the-system-restart-required-flag-in-motd).

Comment: So you are asking how to diagnose one *specific reason* to reboot, namely a security update which requires a reboot to become operational. So the question is: How do you diagnose it locally?

Comment: What I want to get at is: A terminal session via SSH is not fundamentally different from a local one. Whatever you would do locally: You can probably do it remotely as well, including non-interactive ssh sessions which execute a remote command. The ssh exit code is the exit code of the remote command, which allows you to diagnose a remote status without parsing funny outputs.

Comment: And it would be nice to monitor your post and answer questions in comments so that you get useful answers ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check if the file `/var/run/reboot-required` exists.
In a bash script, you can use:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ -f /var/run/reboot-required ]; then
  echo 'A reboot is required'
  restart -r now
fi
```

That way, the script will reboot your machine if a required reboot is pending.

Answer (score 1):

> There are plenty of examples of HOW to reboot a linux machine via SSH.

Since you're logged into that machine through SSH then the way to reboot is the same. `restart -r now` would restart that machine immediately.

> I want to check IF a linux machine needs to be rebooted via SSH.

In that case you could check if your conditions are met in a bash script like,

```
if [ yourCondition ]; then
    restart -r now
fi
```